# could not convert string to float my dataframe df

Tags: dataframe

someone could help me?
i am not able to convert my data frame in float.
i am tring use astype(float) but always receive error in the title of this post.

```
data=pd.read_csv('/Users/IRENE/DOCUMENTS/ire.csv',names=['Bullish','Neutral','Bearish','spread','Average'], 
                 header=None, parse_dates=True)
data.tail()
```

the output is

```
    Bullish     Neutral     Bearish     spread  Average
44833   0,199525    0,192399    0,608076    -0,408551   0,376806082698585
44840   0,239193    0,213256    0,54755     -0,308357   0,376806082698585
44847   0,203647    0,237082    0,559271    -0,355624   0,376806082698585
44854   0,225989    0,211864    0,562147    -0,336158   0,376806082698585
44861   0,265896    0,277457    0,456647    -0,190751   0,376806082698585
```

now the df is in object form.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dataset has `,` instead of `.` hence you are unable to convert.

Try the below snippet

```py
df = df.replace(",",".", regex=False)
df['Neutral'].astype(float)
```

Hope it helps !!! :)